# Is there a way to parse command line options before main function is called?

Tags: c++, c, command-line, clang, command-line-arguments

When a C/C++ program is called like:

```
./prog --arg=42
```

the command line arguments are forwarded to the main function

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
```

where the arguments can be parsed (or forwarded to some library which does the parsing).

I wonder if it is possible to intercept the arguments before the main function is called by the C runtime. 
Since I write a replacement library I cannot use an init function like like `my_lib::init(argc, argv)`.

I am aware of the `__attribute__((constructor))` for a function so it is called before main is invoked, however I don't know how to get the command line arguments in such a tagged function.

Comment: Which compiler are we talking of ? In theory it should be possible to replace parts of the CRT, I did similar things back in the good old DOS days and this should work still. And you might want to add a correct tag to your question. And perhaps you should explain to use why you cannot put your desired logic into the main and need it to be executed before main.

Comment: woops missed the c++/c tags. I am bound to clang/llvm

Comment: Are you sure you can't simply make your code into a `main()` and then have it call `real_main(argc, argv)` after you've finished your processing, and have the users write `real_main()`, or edit that code so that `int main(int argc, char **argv)` becomes `int real_main(int argc, char **argv)`?

Comment: ? Something like this: http://www.eivanov.com/2011/05/how-to-wrapoverwriteoverride-function.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no standard ways to intercept calling the executable's entry point `main()`.

However, you could adjust the linking process of your executable, possibly using the `--wrap` and `-u` options of `ld`, for example. There are further options to replace symbols in the linking process, consider your linker's manual.

Comment: Notice that any way to do that is heavily implementation specific. What might work on Linux/GCC won't work on Windows